# Cloudbees dynamic parameters

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

Does anyone know if it is possible to add dynamic parameters to the configuration of a build job in Cloudbees?

I have a build that has a "choice" build parameter, but I would like to have the values for that choice to come from a function call rather than the fixed list setup in the configuration.

Comment: What type of function call are you imagining? Are you thinking a REST call to a service end-point that would provide the list of values, or are you thinking a Groovy script that runs on Jenkins itself and figures out the values. The former is less flexible but more likely to be supportable from DEV@cloud. Neither is implemented yet as a plugin for Jenkins but would make a fun plugin for somebody to implement

Answer (score 0):

dynamic parameter plugin isn't allowed on CloudBees CI platform as this plugin let user execute arbitrary code on master (populating the parameters list). We (cloudbees) don't let  user have RUN_SCRIPT permission on platform that may introduce some security issues on our multi-tenant architecture.